# Read numpy array image in ITK

Tags: python, numpy, itk

I am trying to figure out how to read an numpy image array into ITK using python and I can't find a way to do that. Could you please provide any hint on which functions from ITK to use?

Comment: I am not familiar with this library but this should help you: https://itkpythonpackage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Quick_start_guide.html#mixing-itk-and-numpy

Comment: sitk.GetImageFromArray